# Calling ASP MVC 3 Controller from View via getJSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, getjson

I'm using jQuery validation plug-in. To check if a username already exists, I've done this in my view:

```
$.validator.addMethod('usernameExists', function (value) {
    var data = {};

    data.username = $('#Username').val();

    $.getJSON('/Account/CheckUsername', data, function (result) {
        if (result.exists == 'true')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    });

    return false;
}, 'Username already exists.');
```

And in my AccountController, I have:

```
public JsonResult CheckUsername(string username)
{
    string test = "false";

    return Json(test);
}
```

I've put a breakpoint into "CheckUsername" and it never comes there, but it comes to the "getJSON" call (I've tried it). Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Obviously, something is wrong with "getJSON"... but what???

Comment: Try removing the first slash from the URL: `$.getJSON('Account/CheckUsername'...`

Comment: If you no not with to reinvent the wheel, there already is builtin [RemoteAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute(VS.98).aspx) for that

Comment: @Mrchief: tried it, does not help.

Comment: try `'/Account/CheckUsername?username='+$('#Username').val();` and replace `data` with `{}` in your getJSON() function. You are basically passing an object i guess that's why.

Answer (score 2):

First, try to call the this action directly from browser: like http://localhost:1212/Account/CheckUsername. If there an error in action you will see it. I assume that you should use JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet to make it work, since getJSON send HTTP GET.

```
return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: what happened? you have tried to call this action directly, but breakpoint didn't come?

Comment: Yes. It's exactly the same as before. Nothing happens on the getJSON call.

Comment: No, I mean, then you enter in the address http://localhost:1818/Account/CheckUsername what do you get? the false string or an empty string or an exception?

Comment: Nothing happens :) It just stays on the "original" page.

Comment: Ok. It isn't right behavior. Seems like your action actually doesn't work. Do you have routes for this action? Do you have any other actions on the AccountController? Do they work properly?

Comment: All my other actions work properly. I added cultures to my routes (like for example, en/US), so it should be en/US/Account/CheckUsername. Anyhow, culture gets added when action is executed, so trying to access Account/CheckUsername withouth culture is in my case, correct.

Comment: ok. anyway, if direct call to the action in browser didn't get the result, then it's not the getJSON. it's about your controller and action. try to return the Content result from the action and again call the action directly, see if it works.

Comment: What do you mean, return the Content result from the action?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470588.aspx. I mean, try to return "false" string directly from action using the Content method. If this works and action can't be called directly from the browser, then check again JSON result. As I've said before use JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet and set HttpGet attribute for the action.

Comment: Ok. Something was terribly wrong with my routing. I turned it off (the custom part), and getJSON is finally working. Sorry all.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("your path here", { username: $('#Username').val() }, function (data) {
        //logic goes here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using,

```
 $.getJSON('@Url.Action("CheckUsername", "Account")', data, function (result) {
```

further more using `"/Account/CheckUsername"`  will be a trouble for you when you are going to deploy the web site.

Comment: then try this for your data variable var data = { username : $('#Username').val()};

Comment: Tried it before. Produces the same result.

Comment: :( then try using $.get instead of .getJson

Comment: I have never used it. Why should it be any different? I don't get it. After trying 10 different tutorials and doing everything "by the book".

Comment: I never used getJASON too :). But I have used get .

Comment: you can check the request is working or not useing firebug or chrome.